# Selenium XPath is not working, the console cant find the element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I know the basics of python and I am trying out Selenium. This page I am on is my schoolwork website. I want to select every single element in the timeline of my homework. I tried to select the whole timeline with XPath or even just one specific homework(elem) but both have this error code:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="jwdd3b016b_acnt"]/div[3]/ul/li[3]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\tomas\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://glnt.edupage.org/timeline/')

#then I log in but that's not important

important_stuff = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jwdd3b016b_acnt"]/div[3]/ul/li[3]')
```

I have no idea what to do. I was under the impression that when u use XPath the code should always work. Am I wrong? (not always I mean, but when the code is correct)

Edit: sorry I forgot here is the HTML of the element:

```
<li class="hwItem m04 d5" data-typ="timeline" data-homeworkid="timeline:2031705" data-date="2020-04-24" data-timelineid="2031705">
```

That should do it:

```
<div class="edubarMainNoSkin">
    <div id="jwdd3b016b_acnt" class="hwMainListMain">
        <div class="hwListElem">
            <ul class="hwList timelineMode ">
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: I added the HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately we will need more HTML than that if we are to compare it with your XPath. Your XPath 3 tags higher than the snippet you posted. You could also reference that li directly using the class or data-homeworkid attribute assuming those are unique.

Comment: I went and tried that, but it didn't work. I copied the Xpath through left click so I don't think the XPath is wrong and that's the problem.

Comment: Your XPath could be wrong. There are many things that can change when a page is refreshed. For example, the id you used could have changed as it is a random string. The index of subsequent elements could have also changed (although less likely). I would need to see more HTML than the single element you are referencing.

Comment: Will those be enough. I don't wanna copy the whole thing it's quite long.

Comment: Based on what you posted, assuming the indexes for subelements are correct, your XPath should be valid. You may be having an issue due to iframes or shadow-doms

Comment: Since that's way beyond my understanding should I just give up or is there any way to solve this? (from what I just found by a google search I probably have a problem with iframes)

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without a full view of the HTML. You can check if the element you are requesting is within an iframe by looking at the HTML page source.

Comment: Yeah I can't find anything so I am just gonna drop it. But thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say much without seen more of the HTML.

> //*[@id="jwdd3b016b_acnt"]/div[3]/ul/li[3]

- id part may not be constant.
- It might be inside of an iframe, so you have to switch into it.
- Due to browser rendering, deepness of the div might be changed.(div[3] would be changed)

First find the correct element using developer tools. 
Then while executing using webdriver put a break point and check via developer tools.